# Basic Ember Template Not Rendering in Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ember.js, ember-rails

Forgive me, for I am new to Ember (and the Javascript world as a whole for that matter). I have a rails application created with the `ember-rails` gem, we'll call it 'warthog'

My `application.js` file is as follows:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require handlebars
//= require ember
//= require ember-data
//= require_self
//= require warthog
Warthog = Ember.Application.create();
//= require bootstrap
```

Next is `application.html.haml` file

```
%html
  %head
    %title Warthog
    = stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all"
    = javascript_include_tag "application"
    = javascript_include_tag 'templates/application'
```

For some test output, I have a string in my `application.handlebars` file

```
This is a test
```

The problem is that `javascripts/templates/application.handlebars` does not get rendered.

Here is page source after the request is completed:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Warthog</title>
    <link href="/assets/application.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/assets/handlebars.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/assets/ember.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/assets/ember-data.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/assets/application.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/assets/store.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/assets/controllers/application_controller.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/assets/templates/application.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/assets/routes/application_routes.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/assets/router.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/assets/warthog.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/assets/templates/application.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="//www.google.com/jsapi" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/assets/chartkick.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <meta content="authenticity_token" name="csrf-param" />
    <meta content="afE+P0e6I/KDeVpg/kLi8RvsPAAyYOwD6rE=" name="csrf-token" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='container'>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And the console log

```
DEBUG: ------------------------------- ember.js?body=1:394
DEBUG: Ember.VERSION : 1.0.0 ember.js?body=1:394
DEBUG: Handlebars.VERSION : 1.0.0 ember.js?body=1:394
DEBUG: jQuery.VERSION : 1.10.0 ember.js?body=1:394
DEBUG: ------------------------------- ember.js?body=1:394
Assertion failed: The view helper only takes a single argument ember.js?body=1:394
(anonymous function) ember.js?body=1:394
Ember.assert ember.js?body=1:53
(anonymous function) ember.js?body=1:25789
anonymous application.js?body=1:10
(anonymous function) handlebars.js?body=1:2214
Ember.View.Ember.CoreView.extend.render ember.js?body=1:20335
Ember.CoreView.Ember.Object.extend._renderToBuffer ember.js?body=1:19272
Ember.View.Ember.CoreView.extend._renderToBuffer ember.js?body=1:20915
superWrapper ember.js?body=1:1218
(anonymous function) ember.js?body=1:19253
Ember.Instrumentation.instrument ember.js?body=1:1662
Ember.CoreView.Ember.Object.extend.renderToBuffer ember.js?body=1:19252
Ember.View.Ember.CoreView.extend.createElement ember.js?body=1:20737
Ember.merge.insertElement ember.js?body=1:21686
Ember.View.Ember.CoreView.extend._insertElement ember.js?body=1:20665
DeferredActionQueues.flush ember.js?body=1:5459
Backburner.end ember.js?body=1:5545
Backburner.run ember.js?body=1:5584
Ember.run ember.js?body=1:5915
(anonymous function) ember.js?body=1:34656
fire jquery.js?body=1:3065
self.fireWith jquery.js?body=1:3177
jQuery.extend.ready jquery.js?body=1:434
completed jquery.js?body=1:105
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined ember.js?body=1:25589
EmberHandlebars.ViewHelper.Ember.Object.create.helper ember.js?body=1:25589
(anonymous function) ember.js?body=1:25797
anonymous application.js?body=1:10
(anonymous function) handlebars.js?body=1:2214
Ember.View.Ember.CoreView.extend.render ember.js?body=1:20335
Ember.CoreView.Ember.Object.extend._renderToBuffer ember.js?body=1:19272
Ember.View.Ember.CoreView.extend._renderToBuffer ember.js?body=1:20915
superWrapper ember.js?body=1:1218
(anonymous function) ember.js?body=1:19253
Ember.Instrumentation.instrument ember.js?body=1:1662
Ember.CoreView.Ember.Object.extend.renderToBuffer ember.js?body=1:19252
Ember.View.Ember.CoreView.extend.createElement ember.js?body=1:20737
Ember.merge.insertElement ember.js?body=1:21686
Ember.View.Ember.CoreView.extend._insertElement ember.js?body=1:20665
DeferredActionQueues.flush ember.js?body=1:5459
Backburner.end ember.js?body=1:5545
Backburner.run ember.js?body=1:5584
Ember.run ember.js?body=1:5915
(anonymous function) ember.js?body=1:34656
fire jquery.js?body=1:3065
self.fireWith jquery.js?body=1:3177
jQuery.extend.ready jquery.js?body=1:434
completed jquery.js?body=1:105
```

RESOLUTION: The error was in my controller and routes files within Ember; I deleted those and now the page renders

Comment: What happens if you name it `application.js.handlebars`?

Comment: Same issue, still doesn't render

Comment: Change your `application.html.haml` file to not include the `templates/application` file, since it's already included in the `application.js` file. Also, if you don't necessarily need the `ApplicationController` or `ApplicationRoute`, you can safely not define them and Ember will handle that.

Comment: Unfortunately neither option resolved the issue

Comment: What's the data-template-name in browser of your application template?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure your application handlebars template is being injected in this format

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">

</script>
```

or

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" >

</script>
```

Naming is super important in Ember, if your template is getting injected with a different name, like:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="templates/application">

</script>
```

Then you'd need an application view that says to use a different template name than the default template name.

```
Warthog.ApplicationView = Ember.View.extend({
  templateName: 'templates/application'
})
```

Comment: Does the application.handlebars template not get rendered automatically on every request?

Comment: I'm also using the ember-rails gem, and didn't think is was necessary to include the script tags

Comment: What's being rendered client side?

Comment: Sorry, I meant what's coming down in the html

Comment: ahh thanks for clarifying :-) It's plain HTML, I've updated my question with the contents

Comment: does it have script tags around it in the html?

Comment: I added it but it made no change. I'm also referencing the source code for the ember railscast, and none of the handlebars templates have script tags https://github.com/railscasts/410-ember-part-2/tree/master/raffler-after/app/assets/javascripts/templates

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40071/discussion-between-kingpin2k-and-anconia)